# Using RegEx to Find LaTeX Environments

Tags: regex, latex

I have a `LaTeX` code that goes like that:

```
--- text might be here ---
$\begin{cases}
k & l & m \\
x & y & z
\end{cases}$
--- text might be here ---
$\begin{cases}
k & l & m \\
x & y & z
\end{cases}$
--- text might be here ---
$\begin{cases}
k & l & m \\
x & y & z
\end{cases}$
--- text might be here ---
```

I created this `regex` to capture each of the `cases` environments:

```
\\begin\{cases\}((\s*.*\s*)*)\\end\{cases\}
```

What happened is that it matched starting the first `\begin{cases}` to the last `\end{cases}`, while I need it to match each environment independently, that is, to match the first `\end{cases}` after each `\begin{cases}` it matches.

Note that spaces, linebreaks, and tabs are not necessary and might not always be there.

Comment: I don't know which flavour of regex is used in latex so may not give you the right syntax, however you can have to approach here: use lazy quantifiers (`.*?` instead of `.*`) or exclude characters if you can find them appearing only in closing (`[^{]*` or `[^\]` instead of `.*`)

Comment: @MátéJuhász : I tried the lazy quantifier this way `((\s*.*\s*)*?)` and it worked properly. Thank you .. :)

I couldn't use excluding these characters: `\, {, }`, since they could be used within the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can have different approaches here:

1. use lazy quantifiers

   - `.*?` instead of `.*`
2. exclude characters if you can find them appearing only in closing

   - `[^{]*` or `[^\]` instead of `.*`